# Building a workspace (J2ME) on Eclipse 3.6.0

Tags: eclipse, build, java-me, workspace, java-wireless-toolkit

I am beginning work on development/maintenance of a J2ME MIDlet application that uses the Nokia N97 SDK. As a first step (I have never developed J2ME/Java applications before), I completed the following steps on Eclipse 3.6.0 Helios:

1. Imported the project using the following step:
   File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace
   Select root directory as TeleDB1 (the name of the directory that contains the files).
2. When I click on Finish after these steps, Eclipse automatically builds my new workspace. This step is unsuccessful. I get the following errors:

   1. Errors running builder 'Preverification' on project 'TeleDB1'.
   2. org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(Lorg/object/web/asm/ClassVisitor;Z)V

This is what I have tried:
1. Right-click on the project, Properties -> Java Build Path shows the following libraries:
  a. org-netbeans-modules-mobility-antext.jar - missing
  b. J2ME Library (failed to get library information).

These are my questions:
1. How can I get this project to compile?
2. How do I resolve the errors in the Libraries/Build Path?

I think I have set up my environment for running J2ME applications correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I have situation as yours, and I find the way to solve it.

Right-click on the project---->properties---->j2me---->device---->manage device,choose a device you like.